# What control is this numeric textbox with up and down buttons?

Tags: java, user-interface, user-controls

I feel silly asking but cannot find it anywhere.

[image: numeric textbox with up and down buttons]

What is this, can it be implemented in java or is it just a jtextarea with 2 buttons?

Comment: Looks about `14.7` inches.

Comment: That's a [`JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html).

Comment: Don't know about Java but in .net this is known as a NumericUpDown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a `JSpinner`. Learn more at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html